# Gallery Vault verification

Tags: gallery-vault

I recently had to factory reset my phone  but now I have my apps back. When I went on gallery Vault and tried to click on a picture it said that the file was encrypted and I needed to verify my email. At first it took me to a page to type in an authorization code that was sent to my email. I typed in the code but when I try to look at pictures it asks for verification again but when I click verify now it doesn't do anything. Does anyone know how to get the files back?